# Can a Drupal site design (not just colors, fonts, etc -- template stuff) be replicated over multiple drupal sites?

Tags: theming

I will apologize in advance for using the L word...but in Lotus Notes there is the concept of a Template file that holds all the design elements of a database...fields, views, forms, etc. -- has a .ntf extension.  That template can then be used as the design model for other notes databases which have .nsf extensions.  For instance if I have a business model where all my customers do the same thing - say bands keeping track of songs and tours.  I have one bandmaster.ntf file and band01.nsf, band02.nsf, band03.nsf, etc.  The data in each .nsf file is specific to each band...but the design of the database is exactly the same.  Each db inherits it's master design from the one .ntf file.

If I have say a contact form and need to add a new field to it ... say "Alternate Email" -- I open the design of the .ntf file and add that field to my contact form.  Then I 'refresh' the design of all my bandxx.nsf databases and they all now have the new field.

Is there any way to do something like that in Drupal?  Is there a way to export maybe a site's design and use that as the design structure for one or more sites??  I'm just getting started with Drupal.  Thank you for any information.

ER

Comment: Yes, you can install your theme on may sites. And you can install your module with it's db schema on many sites. And you have many way to run many fronts with the same codebase (modules and/or themes), for example multisite or domain access. Sadly, I don't think your question is specific enough for us to know what exactly would suit your needs.

Comment: I think you're confusing people with the word "design", as "design of the database" would normally be considered "functionality" here. It's possible that the module you look for is [features](http://drupal.org/project/features), but as @Mołot says, your question is to broad for the site.

Comment: You can also do a multisite which all is one code base for multiple sites across multiple databases

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback...yes I agree that I am confusing people with the choice of terms...I'm still figuring out what to call things in Drupal.  I did lots of reading yesterday on multisites which seems to be the path I need to go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be able to replicate additional fields that you may add to bundles on a "master" site to several other sites, you may use [Bundle Copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy).

This project provides export/import support for:

- Node types
- Taxonomy
- User
- Field API fields
- Field groups

It will only export/import the bundle definition, not the content.

For a more elaborate export/import module that not only handles fields, but whole features, take a look at [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).

From the module's description:

> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal module except that it declares its components (e.g. views, contexts, CCK fields, etc.) in its .info file so that it can be checked, updated, or reverted programmatically.